# is it possible to export azure devops pipelines run history in excel format?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to analyze azure devops build and release pipelines run, ie number of build succeeded or failed, number of job runs within the interval etc. This type of analysis can easily be done if we can import build and release pipelines history in excel format. In azure devops i could not found any feature to do this. Is it possible to export build and release pipelines run history in excel format?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct way to export in excel, however, you can use the [Azure DevOps REst API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the data and export into excel. Let me know if you need any help with the REST API

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can select the specific attributes which you need from the response and export to *.csv file directly, the *.csv file can be opened with Microsoft excel.

A sample for your reference:

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}",
   [string]$project = "ProjectName",
   [string]$user = "user",
   [string]$token = "PAT/Password",
   [string]$Filename = 'D:\temp\PipelineHistory.csv'
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

#BaseUrl
$buildsURL = "$collectionurl/$project/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"

#Response           
$builds = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $buildsURL -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}).value

Write-host "Count of succeeded builds:" ($builds | where({$_.result -eq 'succeeded'})).count
Write-host "Count of failed builds:" ($builds | where({$_.result -eq 'failed'})).count

$results = @()

foreach($build in $builds){

    $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "BuildID" = $build.id
          "BuildNumber" = $build.buildNumber
          "Status" = $build.status
          "Result" = $build.result

        } 

    $results += $customObject       
}

$results | Select `
            BuildID,
            BuildNumber,
            Status,
            Result | export-csv -Path $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Where do you use that codes snippet? What language is it? Some context would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

As Jayendran said, we can use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to export the pipeline run history in excel format.

Here is my powershell script sample:

```
$strURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"
$filePath="D:\"
$fileName=$filePath+"\pipeline.json"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $strURL -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method GET -OutFile $fileName
```

You can add a powershell task to the agent job to run the above script.So you can download the pipeline history to the local in `.json` format.

**Note** that you need to use the private agent to run and check the "**Allow scripts to access the OAuth token**" option in the agent job if you use the authentication method in my script .

I am here to take the build pipeline as an example. The same is true for the release pipeline.

**Update**:

Then you can use the **JSON-to-Excel** tool, which allows you to quickly convert data in Excel.
Go to the Office App Store https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104381080 and add it for free.

After opening it with Excel or Excel Online, you can see that a JSON to Excel tab has been added to Excel. Click to open and select Launch JSON to Excel.In the open JSON to Excel, enter the JSON data, then click on GO.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hugh Lin for your valuable solution. This would solve my lots for problem. But i see that output is not in .xlsx format, it's in json format. Anyway we can parse json also to get desired results.

Comment: @PushkarRajSindal,you can use Json-to-Excel tool to convert your Json data to excel,please see my update